# Unity 5 - Halo effect doesn't appear fully when there is a background image in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, sprite, light

Hi I have a problem in Unity with Halo effect not appearing fully when there is a background image added to the scene. I am creating a 2D game with a background image sprite. Upon collision/trigger with a gameobject a Halo should appear but all I get is a color change on the object that has the halo attached rather than the full halo. The Halo appears fully ok if I remove the background image. The Halo also does appear in the Scene view window in 3D mode even with the background image added but not in the Game view window.

I have tried putting the background on a different sorting layer etc without success. The gameobject the halo should appear around is just a standard cube object as I am prototyping my game before I use own sprites. I am thinking its some sort of issue with rendering. Anyone have any tips or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Something might set up a different render order once you start the game. Look for `sortingLayerID` `sortingLayerName` or `sortingOrder` called on a renderer. Or maybe `renderQueue` called on a material. If not, try using these funcions to force your flare in front of everything else.

You can also edit a material's renderQueue by setting the inspector to Debug mode, and editing the Custom Render Queue value (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html).

Another idea: maybe you have a collider in front of the flare. On your Lens Flare script change Ignore Layers to 'Everything', this will make sure the flare is drawn no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am fairly new to Unity and have limited knowledge in that area. Basically I am developing a 2D breakout style game. There is a  Halo effect component on the Paddle which is by default turned off. When then paddle collects/collides bonus object then the Halo is turned on. This works ok if there are no background image.

Comment: (continuing from above). Any idea how I could this via code?

Comment: I can't tell precisely what is going on in your case... Have you tried the above? If you're still not sure, you could make a stripped-down version of your project, with just the elements that show the problem. Upload it somewhere temporary and I will have a look.